# Scheme: How to check if all elements of a list are identical

Tags: list, lambda, scheme, equality

I'd like to create a Scheme function that yields true if it is passed a list that is composed entirely of identical elements. Such a list would be '(1 1 1 1). It would yield false with something like '(1 2 1 1).

This is what I have so far:

```
    (define (list-equal? lst)
      (define tmp (car lst))
      (for-each (lambda (x) 
                   (equal? x tmp))
                 lst)
      )
```

Clearly this is incorrect, and I'm new to this. I guess I'm unable to express the step where I'm supposed to return `#t` or `#f`.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: 
I fiddled a bit and found a solution that seems to work very well, and with a minimal amount of code:

```
(define (list-equal? lst)
 (andmap (lambda (x) 
        (equal? x (car lst)))
      lst))
```

Thanks again for the help everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Minimal amount of code, if you don't care that it only works for numbers:

```
(define (list-equel? lst)
  (apply = lst))
```

Examples:

```
> (list-equel? '(1 1 2 1))
#f
> (list-equel? '(1 1 1 1))
#t
> (list-equel? '(1))
#t
```

Comment: Definitely the best solution, and I can't believe I didn't think of it.  Good call.

Comment: Though you don't even need the length condition.  `(equal?)` with no arguments => `#t`.

Comment: Fun.  When I tested the idea, I subconsciously corrected it to `equal?`.  I think I'll fix that for @aaz.

Comment: @JasonFruit: In standard Scheme, `equal?` is not variadic the way `=` is. :-) (I tested with Racket, for example: "equal?: expects 2 arguments, given 3: 1 2 3") You're going to have to use folding, sorry. :-P

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young --- Ah.  I was misled by guile --- Guile 1.8, that is.  I'll revert with a comment.

Answer (score 2):

The `andmap` solution is nice, but if `andmap` is not available, you can use this. It uses basic operations (and, or, null check, equality check) and handles empty lists and one element lists. Similar to Sean's implementation, but no helper definition is necessary.

```
(define (list-equal? args)
  (or (or (null? args)
          (null? (cdr args)))
      (and (eq? (car args) (cadr args))
           (list-equal? (cdr args)))))
```

Comment: `(or 1 2 3)` is also legal.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (list-equal? lst)
    (if (= (cdr lst) null)
        true
        (and (equal? (car lst) (cadr lst))
             (list-equal? (cdr lst)))))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either, I think it gets to the end and complains that it can't use cadr on a lone element. I am using racket/Pretty Big if this makes a difference.

Comment: This will blow up on a list with one element. EDIT: Joseph is right, it will blow up on any list when you get to the end of it.

Comment: @joseph: You're right. Just the small change that I just made should fix it.

Comment: This will still blow up when you try to take the `cdr` of the empty list. For your implementation, you should check first that `lst` is not `null` and then that `(cdr lst)` is not `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
(define (list-equal? lst)
 (define (helper el lst)
  (or (null? lst)
      (and (eq? el (car lst))
           (helper (car lst) (cdr lst)))))
 (or (null? lst)
     (helper (car lst) (cdr lst))))
```

This might not be the cleanest implementation, but I think it will correctly handle the cases of empty lists and one-element lists.

Comment: This one works well. Thanks a lot, I think I have the hang of this.

Answer (score 0):

In R6RS there's the `for-all` function, which takes a predicate and a list, and returns `#t` if the predicate returns true for all elements in the list and `#f` otherwise, which is exactly what you need here.

So if you're using R6RS (or any other scheme dialect that has the `for-all` function), you can just replace `for-each` with `for-all` in your code and it will work.

Comment: It's too bad that for-all is not available for me. But it's good to know I was on the right track.

Comment: This would work, with the added step that you still must check that `lst` is not empty.

Comment: @Sean: Yes, good point. That or get rid of the `tmp` variable and just call `(car lst)` every time in the predicate (which would never get called for the empty list, avoiding the problem).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
(define (list-equal? lst)
  (cond ((< (length lst) 2) #t)
        (#t (and (equal? (car lst) (cadr lst))
             (list-equal? (cdr lst))))))
```

Comment: This is nice, except that it runs in O(n*n) time, instead of the O(n) time (because for each position in the list, the length of the remainder of the list is computed).  If this were adjusted to have the base case be `(or (null? lst) (null? (cdr lst)))`, it would have much better runtime, as well as being nice and concise.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers in this thread all seem too complicated (I read through them all), so here's my take on it:

```
(define (all-equal? lst)
  (define item (car lst))
  (let next ((lst (cdr lst)))
    (cond ((null? lst) #t)
          ((equal? item (car lst)) (next (cdr lst)))
          (else #f))))
```

(It does not work with an empty list, by design. It's easy to add a `(if (null? lst) #t ...)` if necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

A short, concise solution:

```
#lang racket
(define (all-equal? lst)
  (for/and
      ([i (in-permutations lst)])
    (equal? (first i) (second i))))

; TEST CASES

(require rackunit)

(check-false (all-equal? '(1 2 3)))
(check-true (all-equal? '(1 1 1)))
(check-true (all-equal? '()))
```

Note that this uses racket, so this may not work with your scheme implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution:

```
(define (all-same ls)
    (cond
     ((or (null? ls)
          (null? (cdr ls))) #t)
     (else (and (equal? (car ls) (next ls))
                (all-same (cdr ls)))))))

(define (next ls)
    (cond
     ((or (null? ls)
          (null? (cdr ls))) '())
     (else (cadr ls)))))
```

Answer (score -1):

For is bad in these languages. Try

```
(define list-equal?
 (lambda (lst)
   (if (= lst null)
   (true)
   (foldr = (car lst) (cdr lst))
)))
```

Comment: That won't work. You're comparing an element of a list to a boolean result.